# Gitlab CI variables in jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've got some trouble defining a job. I'm in an early stage of defining my pipeline and I'm trying to solve my problems with variables :). I've got a few subfolder under in gcp/live/development and I'm trying to `cd` them and then run terraform stuff:

```yaml
.plan-development:
  variables:
    ENVIRONMENT: "development"
    TERRAFORM_DEVELOPMENT_PATH: "gcp/live/development"
    TF_ROOT: ${TERRAFORM_DEVELOPMENT_PATH}/${CI_JOB_NAME%-plan-development}
  stage: plan-development
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - gitlab-terraform plan
    - gitlab-terraform plan-json
  artifacts:
    name: plan-${ENVIRONMENT}-${CI_JOB_NAME%-plan-development}
    paths:
      - ${TF_ROOT}/plan.cache
    reports:
      terraform: ${TF_ROOT}/plan.json
```

But according to my failing pipeline, the first script part `cd ${TF_ROOT}` doesn't enter the expected folder at `gcp/live/development/cloud-nat`.

I've got some debug outout, which tells me following:

```
$ cd ${TF_ROOT}
$ pwd && ls
/builds/b79ya_1j/0/devops/terraform/gcp/live/development
cloud-nat
firewall
gke
vpc
$ echo "${CI_JOB_NAME%-plan-development}"
cloud-nat
```

Am I missing something combing two variables (`TF_ROOT: ${TERRAFORM_DEVELOPMENT_PATH}/${CI_JOB_NAME%-plan-development}`)?

Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something combing two variables (TF_ROOT:
> ${TERRAFORM_DEVELOPMENT_PATH}/${CI_JOB_NAME%-plan-development})?

The issue is that Gitlab in `variables section`, doesn't perform bash operations, like you attempt here

```
${CI_JOB_NAME%-plan-development}
```

Gitlab `literally` searches for the variable named `CI_JOB_NAME%-plan-development`

That's why when it creates the **TF_ROOT** variable its value is `gcp/live/development/` since it could not find the variable named `CI_JOB_NAME%-plan-development`